# Delayed stored procedure execution

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

We are having issues with one of our servers. When executing a stored procedure, it can take seconds to return data. Sometimes it is milliseconds. I don't think it is a parameter sniffing issue as it happens with multiple stored procedures.

1. When I ran `whoisactive` during one of these calls I get no wait stats for it.
2. When I look in QueryStore for the stored procedure, the stats that it is millisecond fast.
3. When I run `sp_BlitzFirst` it does show that we have excessive compilations but they seem to be around table variables and temp tables.
4. When running the stored procedure in SSMS with `STATISTIC_IO, TIME ON`, it reports that it only worked for a few milliseconds but the elapsed time was 1463 milliseconds.

> SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time =
> 1 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
> Table
> '#TempTable______________________________________________________________________________________________000000C6E4C1'. Scan count 0, logical reads 7, physical reads 0, page server reads 0,
> read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads
> 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads
> 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0. Table 'Worktable'. Scan count
> 2, logical reads 44, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead
> reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob
> physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob
> page server read-ahead reads 0.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
> SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time =
> 0 ms. Table 'RealTable'. Scan count 7, logical reads 63, physical
> reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server
> read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob
> page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server
> read-ahead reads 0. Table
> '#TempTable______________________________________________________________________________________________000000C6E4C1'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1, physical reads 0, page server reads 0,
> read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads
> 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads
> 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1463
> ms.

**Edit:** I ran profiler to see what was happening between SQL Server and my machine. I called the stored procedure at 12:51:43.080 and I see `Select @@SPID` happening in 0 milliseconds.

Then I see the stored procedure being call with a `SQL:BatchStarting` and `SQL:StmtStarting` both at 12:51:43.087. I then get a `SP:Starting` for the stored procedure at 12:51:47.357. That's 4 seconds to actually start.

What is going on in between?

The statements in the stored procedure only take 3 milliseconds to run.

I'm kinda at a loss here. Any ideas on where to look next?

**UPDATE:** We narrowed down what seems to be causing the delayed stored procedure execution in the SP we are testing with.  One of the parameters is a HierarchyID.  Most of the time when calling this SP and passing in the HierarchyID we see a delay of anywhere between 1 and 7 seconds BEFORE the stored proc STARTS executing.  I know people want the execution plan but the plan is the same when it runs quickly or when it is delayed.  It doesn't seem to be the plan.  It literally looks like it is having a hard time looking in the plan cache for the plan or like it wanted to compile, taking a long time, each time it runs.  We changed the parameter to be a varchar instead and the SP executes immediately.  Of course this means we have to deal with an implicit conversion from varchar to HierarchyID.

- When trying to view the plan SQL Sentry it says a query plan can't be collected some of the time. However, when the SP runs quickly, it can collect a plan.  This is what led us to investigate the parameter issue.
- This server is in an AG (sorry I didn't mention that earlier) and the issue did not exist on the read only replica.
- We did try freeing the proc cache to see if that was the issue with accessing the plan but it did nothing.  Like I said, we were reaching for straws.

We have seen an issue somewhat like this before (slightly different symptoms) and as much as I hate to admit it we rebooted the server and the issue seemed resolved. We chalked it up to a one time thing.  Unfortunately we have some highly visible work happening this morning so we didn't have time to research further or contact MS for help.  Because of that, I rebooted the server and the issue seems resolved again.  If the issue happens again we will get MS involved.

Comment: Excessive compilation time perhaps? Do you have unusual index setups (partitioning or a lot of indexes)? You may also find this link informative https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/are-long-compile-times-bringing-you-down/ Are you using Table Valued Parameters and the SQL Profiler at the same time? Are you using TVF inlining (SQL Server 2019 only)? Which version *and build number* of SQL Server are you on `select @@version`?

Comment: We do have some SPs that use Table Valued Parameters but the one I am using to test with does not.  It does have an inline tvf in it.  Version = Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU8-GDR) (KB4583459) - 15.0.4083.2 (X64) 
 Nov  2 2020 18:35:09 
 Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: CU9 had a large number of fixes re scalar UDF inlining (sorry not TVF). If you have those, I suggest you upgrade to the latest CU10, and see if that makes a difference

Comment: We have a patch cycle and will go to it soon but I can't do that right now.  It just weird that there is no activity in profiler between the batch starting and the SP starting to execute.  Maybe I am missing the event in profiler but I selected them all in RPC and TSQL.

Comment: Note that using the profiler can itself affect things, especially around large queries or plans, or large TVPs. What about updating statistics on all tables? And when did you last run `DBCC CHECKDB`

Comment: Last CheckDB was Sunday.  It isn't a large query but it does use a recursive CTE.  Performance has been fine for a long time.  I know that doesn't matter but it angers me.  Once the code starts to run, it finishes instantly.  It is almost like the retrieval of the cached query plan is being blocked.  I don't even know if that is possible.

Comment: You might change the filters in Profiler before you start the capture to include more traffic/events and see if there are other things going on that the default filters don't include.

Comment: Have you done any other debugging steps, ie, start with a working boilerplate procedure and then start adding the content of your problematic procedure bit by bit. Have you used a recompile hint to be absolutely sure it's not a parametersniffing issue?

Comment: @Stu I think this might get better answers on [dba.se]

Comment: @JamesL. I think this might get better answers on [dba.se]

Comment: I have already placed the question over there.  We may have narrowed it down to an issue with the query plan cache.  When trying to view the plan SQL Server Sentry it says a query plan can't be collected some of the time.  When the SP runs quickly, it can collect a plan.  The table this SP references uses a HierarchyID the lookup value.  We are looking into this as a possible issue.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/293893/delayed-stored-procedure-execution-possible-cache-issue